# How to import sfz format orchestral packs into FL studio?

Tags: fl-studio

I have already tried looking at all the BAD tutorials on YouTube on this topic. They are too fast and not suitable for beginners, especially for a noob like me.

I am using [this free orchestral pack](http://virtualplaying.com/virtual-playing-orchestra/), and I wish to use the sfz file format. I have tried the raw `.wav` files, but they are trash and don't sound good.

I found out that I must download Sforzando (the program) in order to use this file format, but I have no idea how to use it.

How do I use Sforzando?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's much too broad. The best answer will be provided by the software's user guide.

Comment: @Aaron please ive looked at the manual it didnt help.

Comment: According to the [Sforzando website](https://www.plogue.com/products/sforzando.html), "[Drop] WAV files directly on the interface, and they will automatically get converted to SFZ 2.0."

Comment: Note that WAV files must be ACIDized before converting, so you'll need to find software to do that. Google search suggests a number of possibilities.

Comment: Here they explain how to use Kontakt in FL studio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3P6MFHVnG0 Replace everything Kontakt related with Sforzando and that should do the trick

Comment: @Aaron i have no idea what you said. I cant see the interface you are talkin about.

Comment: Have you been able to install and use any plugins in any DAW ever?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica no i havent been able to.

Comment: Ok, then the question is way beyond the scope of this site. The question is more like, "what are plugins and how are they used in FL Studio". I recommend learning some basics of how to use FL Studio. I've never used FL Studio, but this page might not be the worst place to start https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-learning/fl-studio-online-manual/html/basics_externalplugins.htm